# zoom specific part of an activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to zoom specific part of activity.for example we all know about magnifier.I want to do like that.Assume that some part of an activity is has very small fonts and user is not able to read that part.so when user clicks on that part that specific part must be zoomed. I want to do like that.

Is it Possible??
Thanks In Advance.

[My Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZTQ9.jpg)

Comment: Please provide more details about your application, you can also post a screenshot of it. It's not clear whether the Activity consists of several parts or it's just one View and you want to zoom parts of it.

Comment: click on MY Screen.you will see an image.as in image "No content available" is in small fonts and i can't read it.so when i click on that part only that part will be zoomed.i want to do that.

Comment: Offtopic: Why not make your UI more phone friendly and use bigger font/lesser information?

Comment: this image is not from my application.i just wanted to explain Egor what i want to do.for some reasons i cannot put my own app's activity.
Thanks.